# Pygame: converting .png file to rect?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

I've been working on this small game for a while and I've encountered a headache. Below you can see that "square1" and "square2" are drawn with pygame. I want to replace them with images, but it messes up the colliderect stuff I've done. Is it possible to "convert" a loaded .png image into a rect object?

```
import pygame
import os

from test_menu import drawmenu
from game_over import player1wins
from game_over import player2wins
from game_over import tie
pygame.init()

while True: 
    screen_size = (1080, 400)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

    background = (255,255,255)
    image = pygame.image.load("background(1).png")
    imagerect = image.get_rect()
    wall_left = pygame.Rect(0,0,1,950)
    wall_right = pygame.Rect(1080,0,1,950)

    square1 = pygame.Rect(750, 350, 20, 20)
    square2 = pygame.Rect(330, 350, 20, 20)

    x_movement = 0
    y_movement = 0
    x2_movement = 0
    y2_movement = 0

    accelx1 = 0
    accely1 = 0
    accelx2 = 0
    accely2 = 0

    jumping = False
    jumping2 = False

    def health_bars(player1_health, player2_health):
        if player1_health > 75:
            player1_health_color = (62, 219, 41)
        elif player1_health > 50:
            player1_health_color = (239, 212, 9)
        else:
            player1_health_color = (239, 9, 9)

        if player2_health > 75:
            player2_health_color = (62, 219, 41)
        elif player2_health > 50:
            player2_health_color = (239, 212, 9)
        else:
            player2_health_color = (239, 9, 9)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, player1_health_color, (70, 50, player1_health, 25))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, player2_health_color, (900, 50, player2_health, 25))

    player1_health = int(100)
    player2_health = int(100)

    drawmenu()

    while True:
        screen.fill(background)
        screen.blit(image, imagerect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), square1)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), square2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), wall_left)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), wall_right)
        health_bars(player1_health, player2_health)
        pygame.display.update()
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        pygame.time.delay(20)

        #MOVEMENT P1

        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] == 1:
            x_movement += -1
        elif keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] == 1:
            x_movement += 1
        else:
            x_movement = 0

        #MOVEMENT P2

        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] == 1:
            x2_movement += -1
        elif keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] == 1:
            x2_movement += 1
        else:
            x2_movement = 0

        #MAX SPEED P1
        if x_movement < -7:
            x_movement = -7
        if x_movement > 7:
            x_movement = 7
        if y_movement < -7:
            y_movement = -7
        if y_movement > 7:
            y_movement = 7

        #MAX SPEED P2
        if x2_movement < -7:
            x2_movement = -7
        if x2_movement > 7:
            x2_movement = 7
        if y2_movement < -7:
            y2_movement = -7
        if y2_movement > 7: 
            y2_movement = 7

        #COLLISION (WALL) P1

        if square1.colliderect(wall_left):
            player2_health -= 0.5
            x_movement = 0
            y_movement = 0
            if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] == 1:
                x_movement += 1

        if square1.colliderect(wall_right):
            player2_health -= 0.5
            x_movement = 0
            y_movement = 0
            if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] == 1:
                x_movement += -1

        #COLLISION (WALL) P2

        if square2.colliderect(wall_left):
            player1_health -= 0.5
            x2_movement = 0
            y2_movement = 0
            if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] == 1:
                x2_movement += 1

        if square2.colliderect(wall_right):
            player1_health -= 0.5
            x2_movement = 0
            y2_movement = 0
            if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] == 1:
                x2_movement += -1


        #COLLISION (ATTACK) P1
        if square1.colliderect(square2) and keys_pressed[pygame.K_g] == 1:
            player2_health -= 1

        #COLLISION (ATTACK) P2
        if square2.colliderect(square1) and keys_pressed[pygame.K_p] == 1:
            player1_health -= 1

        #JUMPING P1
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] == 1:
            if jumping2 == False:
                jumping2 = True

                y2_movement = -30
                accely2 = 1

        square2 = square2.move(x2_movement, y2_movement)

        x2_movement += accelx2
        y2_movement += accely2

        if jumping2 == True:
            if square2.y >= 350:
                jumping2 = False

                square2.y = 350
                y2_movement = 0
                accely2 = 0

        #JUMPING P2
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] == 1:
            if jumping == False:
                jumping = True

                y_movement = -30
                accely1 = 1

        square1 = square1.move(x_movement, y_movement)

        x_movement += accelx1
        y_movement += accely1

        if jumping == True:
            if square1.y >= 350:
                jumping = False

                square1.y = 350
                y_movement = 0
                accely1 = 0

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(20)

        if player2_health == 0 and player1_health !=0:
            pygame.time.delay(400)
            player1wins()
            pygame.time.delay(3000)
            drawmenu()
            break
        elif player1_health == 0 and player2_health !=0:
            pygame.time.delay(400)
            player2wins()
            pygame.time.delay(3000)
            drawmenu()
            break
        if player1_health == 0 and player2_health == 0:
            pygame.time.delay(400)
            tie()
            pygame.time.delay(3000)
            drawmenu()
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to get a rect with the dimensions of an image/surface is to call the [`get_rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method of the surface.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# Use the convert or convert_alpha methods to improve the performance.
IMAGE = pg.image.load('an_image.png').convert_alpha()
rect = IMAGE.get_rect()  # A rect with the dimensions of the image.
# Set the position of the rect.
rect.x = 100
rect.y = 200

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    # Move the rect.
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        rect.x += 2
    elif keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        rect.x -= 2

    # Draw everything.
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    # Just pass the rect as the destination argument.
    screen.blit(IMAGE, rect)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

You can also use the other [rect attributes](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to set its position:

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
```

I'd actually store the position of the sprite/object in a vector, because that allows for more precise movement (rects can only store ints and truncate floats). To move the object I'd add the velocity (another vector) to it first and then set the rect's  `center` or `topleft` attribute to the new position vector. The rect would still be needed as the blit position and for collision detection. Here's an example from a sprite template:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way that this can be done. However you can just keep a `Surface` object to render the image and another `Rect` object to handle all the collision detection business.

This is very common.

**How to do it:**

- Create the `Rect` object.
- Create the `Surface` object.
- Load in a .png file and blit it onto the `Surface` that you have just created.
- Make sure that the x and y values of the `Rect` object and the `Surface` object are the same at the end of every frame.

I have included some example code to get you started. I commented out the code with loading in the images though.

**To use your own images:**

- copy the image files into the directory you want. (If in doubt, choose the directory of the script)
- Get the correct path name and use it in the code below.

Now you can use the `Rect`s for collision detection and moving and the image surfaces will always be drawn wherever the `Rect` is.

**Note**: this approach is commonly done in an object-oriented fashion.

I hope that this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

**Example code**

```
# create Rects
square1 = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 100, 100)
square2 = pygame.Rect(100, 300, 100, 100)

# create the image surfaces
img = pygame.Surface((100, 100))

image_file = pygame.image.load("path/to/image_file")
img.blit(image_file, [0, 0])

img2 = pygame.Surface((100,100))


image_file2 = pygame.image.load("path/to/image_file")
img.blit(image_file2, [0, 0])
```

And to blit these `Surface`s onto the screen:

```
# draw the image Surfaces
screen.blit(img, [square1.x, square1.y])
screen.blit(img2, [square2.x, square2.y])
```